# Altering Bundle savedInstanceState

Tags: java, android

I want to create an app that acts as frontend to launch an emulator with preloaded game.

I have the emu source code, but I can't edit it. 
In the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method of the emulator's main activity there is this line:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null)
    currentGame = savedInstanceState.getString("currentGame");
```

Which seems the line that makes the emulator run the latest game if one is found when the activity is (re)created.

Is there a way to edit the savedInstanceState so that it contains the `currentGame` string?

Answer (score 0):

when the activity is first created the `savedInstanceState` is null, and in subsequent calls it's not. To make sure that the `savedInstanceState` is not null, there is a method called `onRestoreInstanceState()` that you should override, and for sure it has the string you're looking for.

but i think that what you realy want is to send an intent to that activity with a `Bundle` already filled with that string. if it's not what you want please explain a little more what is your problem.

Comment: I can't edit the emulator source, I can only use my application to externally alterate the emulator bundle if it's possible.

Comment: try this:`intent.getExtras().putCharSequence("currentGame", "yourString");`
`startActivity(intent);`